# CSS3 Card Flip, Jquery returns undefined function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Simple problem, but can't figure it out. The following basic lines of jquery are not cooperating with me. Browser returns following error: *Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function*

```
$('.flip').click(function() {
    document.find('#card').addClass('flipped');
});
```

All the classes and ids called exist in the docs. No problems there.

Comment: What does `document` represent? Is it the current window, generated html or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `document` and `find` from `document.find('#card').addClass('flipped');` as you don't need that.

```
  $('.flip').click(function() {
        $('#card').addClass('flipped');
    });
```

**demo:**

http://code-chunk.com/chunks/543b7d86025c1/flip-it

Answer (score 0):

You will get `undefined is not a function` error whenever jquery not able to find element using specified selector and you call any function on it i.e. for function calling on undefined object.

You should use `find()` with `document` like below

```
$('.flip').click(function() {
    //wrap document inside $()
    $(document).find('#card').addClass('flipped');
});
```

But as you are trying to find using `id` (**which must be unique through out the DOM**), then use `id` selector directly instead of `find()`

```
$('.flip').click(function() {
    $('#card').addClass('flipped');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are referring the element by the `id`, you can directly invoke it:

```
$('#card').addClass('flipped');
```